# Possible autolayout crash in tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

In a tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath I get a very strange crash while dequueing the cell.
The crash is shown by the exception breakpoint to be on the line where a cell is obtained by calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

Here is the exception log:

```
*** Assertion failure in NSComparisonResult ComparePriorityVectorsForVariables(NSISObjectiveLinearExpression *, NSISVariable *, NSISVariable *)(), /SourceCache/Foundation_Sim/Foundation-1047.25/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:30
```

And then :

```
Objective: {objective 0xc3c84c0: <998:99, 750:212, 251:5975, 250:742> + <750:1, 250:1>*0x12e092e0.negError{id: 2911} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x12e09320.negError{id: 2909} + <998:1, 251:-1, 250:1>*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x135ef7f0.negError{id: 4349} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x135ef7f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4348} + <998:2>*0x135ef990.negError{id: 4342} + <998:1, 251:-2>*0x135ef9c0.negError{id: 4344} + <998:1, 251:2>*0x135ef9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4343} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x135ef9f0.negError{id: 4346} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x135ef9f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4345} + <998:2>*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + <998:1>*0x135efb60.negError{id: 4337} + <998:1>*0x135efb60.posErrorMarker{id: 4336} + <998:2>*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x135f0010.negError{id: 4317} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x135f0010.posErrorMarker{id: 4316} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x135f0040.negError{id: 4320} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x135f0040.posErrorMarker{id: 4319} + <998:1, 251:2>*0x135f0070.negError{id: 4324} + <998:1, 251:-2>*0x135f0070.posErrorMarker{id: 4323} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x135f01b0.negError{id: 4326} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x135f01b0.posErrorMarker{id: 4325} + <998:2>*0x135f01e0.negError{id: 4328} + <251:1>*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + <998:2, 251:-1>*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + <251:3>*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281} + <999:2>*0x1362eba0.negError{id: 2886} + <999:2>*0x1362edb0.negError{id: 2883} + <251:1>*0x1362ffd0.marker{id: 2820} + <750:-1>*0x13630000.marker{id: 2818} + <750:-1>*0x136306d0.marker{id: 2812} + <750:-1>*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + <250:1>*0x13630b20.marker{id: 2824} + <250:1>*0x13630b50.marker{id: 2822} + <250:1>*0x13631030.marker{id: 2834} + <250:1>*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x13864db0.negError{id: 2942} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x13864eb0.negError{id: 2944} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14181b70.negError{id: 4360} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14181bb0.posErrorMarker{id: 4361} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14182ef0.negError{id: 4356} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14182f30.negError{id: 4358} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x141838c0.negError{id: 4364} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14183900.posErrorMarker{id: 4365} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14183e40.negError{id: 4368} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14183e80.negError{id: 4370} + <998:1, 251:2>*0x143e73a0.negError{id: 4295} + <998:1, 251:-2>*0x143e73a0.posErrorMarker{id: 4294} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x143e73d0.negError{id: 4298} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x143e73d0.posErrorMarker{id: 4297} + <998:1, 251:3>*0x143e8f30.negError{id: 4289} + <998:1, 251:-3>*0x143e8f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4288} + <998:1>*0x143e9030.negError{id: 4286} + <998:1>*0x143e9030.posErrorMarker{id: 4285} + <998:1>*0x143e9110.negError{id: 4292} + <998:1>*0x143e9110.posErrorMarker{id: 4291} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x143eb9c0.negError{id: 4310} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x143eb9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4309} + <998:1>*0x143eb9f0.negError{id: 4313} + <998:1>*0x143eb9f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4312} + <998:-1, 251:1>*0x143f8970.marker{id: 4460} + <251:1>*0x143f89a0.marker{id: 4462} + <251:1>*0x143f8cb0.marker{id: 4464} + <251:1>*0x143f90b0.marker{id: 4466} + <250:1>*0x143f9d80.marker{id: 4472} + <251:1>*0x143fa830.marker{id: 4470} + <998:1>*0x143fad00.negError{id: 4475} + <998:1>*0x143fad00.posErrorMarker{id: 4474} + <998:2>*0x143fad30.negError{id: 4478} + <998:1>*0x143fad60.negError{id: 4485} + <998:1>*0x143fad60.posErrorMarker{id: 4484} + <998:2, 251:-1>*0x143fad90.negError{id: 4488} + <251:1>*0x143fad90.posErrorMarker{id: 4487} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x143fadc0.negError{id: 4491} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x143fadc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4490} + <998:2>*0x143fadf0.negError{id: 4499} + <998:1>*0x143fae20.negError{id: 4502} + <998:1>*0x143fae20.posErrorMarker{id: 4501} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x143fae50.negError{id: 4517} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x143fae50.posErrorMarker{id: 4516} + <998:1>*0x143fae80.negError{id: 4520} + <998:1>*0x143fae80.posErrorMarker{id: 4519} + <998:1, 251:1>*0x143faeb0.negError{id: 4524} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0x143faeb0.posErrorMarker{id: 4523} + <998:2>*0x143faee0.posErrorMarker{id: 4530} + <998:1>*0x143faf10.negError{id: 4538} + <998:1>*0x143faf10.posErrorMarker{id: 4537} + <998:2>*0x143faf40.negError{id: 4542} + <998:2>*0x143faf70.negError{id: 4546} + <998:2>*0x143fafa0.posErrorMarker{id: 4549} + <998:2>*0x143faff0.negError{id: 4552} + <998:1>*0x143fb020.negError{id: 4560} + <998:1>*0x143fb020.posErrorMarker{id: 4559} + <998:1>*0x143fb050.posErrorMarker{id: 4562} + <998:1, 251:3>*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x14409070.negError{id: 4379} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x14409140.negError{id: 4381} + <750:1>*0x1440c5b0.negError{id: 4372} + <750:1>*0x1440c5b0.posErrorMarker{id: 4371} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1440c790.negError{id: 4377} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1440d920.negError{id: 4375} + <750:2>*0x15467020.posErrorMarker{id: 4525} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546ba70.negError{id: 4497} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546c280.negError{id: 4504} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546c2c0.negError{id: 4506} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546c560.negError{id: 4481} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546c680.negError{id: 4495} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546ce60.negError{id: 4483} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546f960.negError{id: 4512} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546f9a0.negError{id: 4514} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546fb80.negError{id: 4529} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x1546fbc0.negError{id: 4533} + <750:1, 250:1>*0x1546ffc0.negError{id: 4540} + <750:1, 251:1>*0x15470010.negError{id: 4544} + <251:-2>*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271} + <251:1>*0x155854b0.marker{id: 4273} + <750:-1>*0x155857a0.marker{id: 4275} + <750:-1>*0x15585c40.marker{id: 4277} + <998:-2>*0x15586380.marker{id: 4279} + <998:1, 251:1>*0xc0c8830.negError{id: 4302} + <998:1, 251:-1>*0xc0c8830.posErrorMarker{id: 4301} + <998:1, 251:-2>*0xc0c8860.negError{id: 4305} + <998:1, 251:2>*0xc0c8860.posErrorMarker{id: 4304} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc3b2000.posErrorMarker{id: 2929} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc3c12c0.posErrorMarker{id: 2931} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc3c1cf0.negError{id: 2934} + <750:1, 251:1>*0xc3c1d30.posErrorMarker{id: 2935} + <251:2>*UILabel:0x143f8bb0.Width{id: 4493} + <998:1, 251:1>*UILabel:0x143f92e0.Height{id: 4508} + <998:-1, 251:1>*UILabel:0x143f92e0.Width{id: 4515} + <998:-1, 251:1>*UILabel:0x143f9c60.Height{id: 4534} + <251:1>*UILabel:0x143fa540.Width{id: 4536} + <750:-1>*UIProgressView:0x143f95a0.Height{id: 4527} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x1362ec10.Width{id: 2887} + <999:1>*_UILayoutGuide:0x1362ee20.Width{id: 2884}}
2014-08-21 10:32:28.596 du View[1575:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<NSISEngine: 0xc3c9c60>{ Rows:
    0x12e092e0.posErrorMarker{id: 2910} == 25 + 1*0x13630b20.marker{id: 2824} + 1*0x12e092e0.negError{id: 2911}
    0x12e09320.posErrorMarker{id: 2908} == 72 + 1*0x13630b50.marker{id: 2822} + 1*0x12e09320.negError{id: 2909}
    0x135ef990.posErrorMarker{id: 4341} == 0 + -1*0x15586380.marker{id: 4279} + -1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + 1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + 1*0x135ef990.negError{id: 4342} + 1*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385}
    0x135f01e0.posErrorMarker{id: 4327} == 0 + -1*0x15586380.marker{id: 4279} + 1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + 1*0x135f01e0.negError{id: 4328} + 1*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + -1*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + -1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + 1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335}
    0x1362eba0.posErrorMarker{id: 2885} == 0 + 1*0x1362eba0.negError{id: 2886} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x1362ec10.Width{id: 2887}
    0x1362edb0.posErrorMarker{id: 2882} == 0 + 1*0x1362edb0.negError{id: 2883} + 1*_UILayoutGuide:0x1362ee20.Width{id: 2884}
    0x1362f460.marker{id: 2875} == 0 + 1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + -1*0x136301f0.marker{id: 2816} + 1*0x13630000.marker{id: 2818} + 1*0x13630b20.marker{id: 2824} + -1*0x1362faf0.marker{id: 2828} + -1*0x1362f7f0.marker{id: 2844} + 1*0x1362f730.marker{id: 2851} + 1*0x1362f6a0.marker{id: 2856} + 1*0x1362f610.marker{id: 2860} + -1*0x1362f550.marker{id: 2867} + 1*0x1362f4f0.marker{id: 2870}
    0x1362f4c0.marker{id: 2872} == 0 + 1*0x1362f4f0.marker{id: 2870}
    0x1362f520.marker{id: 2869} == 0 + -1*0x1362fac0.marker{id: 2830} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f580.marker{id: 2865}
    0x1362f5b0.marker{id: 2864} == 0 + -1*0x13630b50.marker{id: 2822} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f5e0.marker{id: 2862}
    0x1362f640.marker{id: 2859} == 0 + -1*0x1362ffd0.marker{id: 2820} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f6d0.marker{id: 2854}
    0x1362f670.marker{id: 2858} == 0 + 1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + -1*0x136301f0.marker{id: 2816} + -1*0x1362f7f0.marker{id: 2844} + 1*0x1362f730.marker{id: 2851} + 1*0x1362f6a0.marker{id: 2856}
    0x1362f700.marker{id: 2853} == 0 + -1*0x136306d0.marker{id: 2812} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f760.marker{id: 2849}
    0x1362f790.marker{id: 2848} == 0 + -1*0x13630220.marker{id: 2814} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f7c0.marker{id: 2846}
    0x13864db0.posErrorMarker{id: 2941} == 90 + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x13864db0.negError{id: 2942}
    0x13864eb0.posErrorMarker{id: 2943} == 96 + 1*0x13631030.marker{id: 2834} + 1*0x13864eb0.negError{id: 2944}
    0x14181b70.posErrorMarker{id: 4359} == 421 + -1*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271} + -1*0x143e8f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4288} + 1*0x143e8f30.negError{id: 4289} + -1*0x143e73a0.posErrorMarker{id: 4294} + 1*0x143e73a0.negError{id: 4295} + -1*0x143e73d0.posErrorMarker{id: 4297} + 1*0x143e73d0.negError{id: 4298} + 1*0x14181b70.negError{id: 4360} + 1*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385}
    0x14181bb0.negError{id: 4362} == 8 + -1*0x155857a0.marker{id: 4275} + 1*0x14181bb0.posErrorMarker{id: 4361}
    0x14182ef0.posErrorMarker{id: 4355} == 6 + 1*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271} + 1*0x14182ef0.negError{id: 4356}
    0x14182f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4357} == 26 + 1*0x155854b0.marker{id: 4273} + 1*0x14182f30.negError{id: 4358}
    0x141838c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4363} == 459 + -1*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271} + -1*0x143e8f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4288} + 1*0x143e8f30.negError{id: 4289} + -1*0x143eb9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4309} + 1*0x143eb9c0.negError{id: 4310} + -1*0x135f0010.posErrorMarker{id: 4316} + 1*0x135f0010.negError{id: 4317} + 1*0x141838c0.negError{id: 4364} + 1*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385}
    0x14183900.negError{id: 4366} == 1 + -1*0x15585c40.marker{id: 4277} + 1*0x14183900.posErrorMarker{id: 4365}
    0x14183e40.posErrorMarker{id: 4367} == 9 + -1*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271} + -1*0x143e8f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4288} + 1*0x143e8f30.negError{id: 4289} + -1*0x143e73a0.posErrorMarker{id: 4294} + 1*0x143e73a0.negError{id: 4295} + -1*0xc0c8830.posErrorMarker{id: 4301} + 1*0xc0c8830.negError{id: 4302} + -1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + 1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + 1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + -1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + 1*0x14183e40.negError{id: 4368}
    0x14183e80.posErrorMarker{id: 4369} == 0 + 1*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281} + 1*0xc0c8860.posErrorMarker{id: 4304} + -1*0xc0c8860.negError{id: 4305} + -1*0x135f0070.posErrorMarker{id: 4323} + 1*0x135f0070.negError{id: 4324} + 1*0x135f01b0.posErrorMarker{id: 4325} + -1*0x135f01b0.negError{id: 4326} + 1*0x135ef9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4343} + -1*0x135ef9c0.negError{id: 4344} + 1*0x14183e80.negError{id: 4370}
    0x143fad30.posErrorMarker{id: 4477} == 651 + -1*0x143f8970.marker{id: 4460} + 1*0x143fad30.negError{id: 4478} + -1*0x143fad90.posErrorMarker{id: 4487} + 1*0x143fad90.negError{id: 4488} + -1*0x143fadc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4490} + 1*0x143fadc0.negError{id: 4491} + -1*UILabel:0x143f8bb0.Width{id: 4493} + 1*0x1435c670.marker{id: 4556}
    0x143faf40.posErrorMarker{id: 4541} == 0 + 1*UILabel:0x143f92e0.Height{id: 4508} + 1*0x143faee0.posErrorMarker{id: 4530} + -1*0x143faee0.negError{id: 4532} + -1*UILabel:0x143f9c60.Height{id: 4534} + 1*0x143faf40.negError{id: 4542}
    0x143faff0.posErrorMarker{id: 4551} == 0 + -1*0x143f96f0.marker{id: 4468} + 1*0x143f9d80.marker{id: 4472} + -1*0x143faf70.posErrorMarker{id: 4545} + 1*0x143faf70.negError{id: 4546} + 1*0x143fafa0.posErrorMarker{id: 4549} + -1*0x143fafa0.negError{id: 4550} + 1*0x143faff0.negError{id: 4552}
    0x14409070.posErrorMarker{id: 4378} == 20 + 1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + 1*0x14409070.negError{id: 4379}
    0x14409140.posErrorMarker{id: 4380} == 1 + 1*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281} + 1*0xc0c8860.posErrorMarker{id: 4304} + -1*0xc0c8860.negError{id: 4305} + 1*0x135f0040.posErrorMarker{id: 4319} + -1*0x135f0040.negError{id: 4320} + -1*0x135f0070.posErrorMarker{id: 4323} + 1*0x135f0070.negError{id: 4324} + 1*0x135ef9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4343} + -1*0x135ef9c0.negError{id: 4344} + 1*0x14409140.negError{id: 4381}
    0x1440c790.posErrorMarker{id: 4376} == 1 + 1*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281} + 1*0x1440c790.negError{id: 4377}
    0x1440d920.posErrorMarker{id: 4374} == 142 + -1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + -1*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + 1*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + 1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + -1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + -1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + 1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + -1*0x135ef9f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4345} + 1*0x135ef9f0.negError{id: 4346} + -1*0x135ef7f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4348} + 1*0x135ef7f0.negError{id: 4349} + 1*0x1440d920.negError{id: 4375} + 1*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385}
    0x15467020.negError{id: 4526} == 2 + 1*0x15467020.posErrorMarker{id: 4525} + -1*UIProgressView:0x143f95a0.Height{id: 4527}
    0x1546ba70.posErrorMarker{id: 4496} == 24 + 1*0x143f8cb0.marker{id: 4464} + 1*0x1546ba70.negError{id: 4497}
    0x1546c280.posErrorMarker{id: 4503} == 0 + 1*0x143fad90.posErrorMarker{id: 4487} + -1*0x143fad90.negError{id: 4488} + 1*0x143fadc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4490} + -1*0x143fadc0.negError{id: 4491} + 1*UILabel:0x143f8bb0.Width{id: 4493} + 1*0x1546c280.negError{id: 4504} + -1*0x143fae50.posErrorMarker{id: 4516} + 1*0x143fae50.negError{id: 4517} + -1*0x143faeb0.posErrorMarker{id: 4523} + 1*0x143faeb0.negError{id: 4524}
    0x1546c2c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4505} == 24 + 1*0x143f90b0.marker{id: 4466} + 1*0x1546c2c0.negError{id: 4506}
    0x1546c560.posErrorMarker{id: 4480} == 6 + 1*0x143f8970.marker{id: 4460} + 1*0x1546c560.negError{id: 4481}
    0x1546c680.posErrorMarker{id: 4494} == 0 + 1*UILabel:0x143f8bb0.Width{id: 4493} + 1*0x1546c680.negError{id: 4495}
    0x1546ce60.posErrorMarker{id: 4482} == 26 + 1*0x143f89a0.marker{id: 4462} + 1*0x1546ce60.negError{id: 4483}
    0x1546f960.posErrorMarker{id: 4511} == 0 + 1*0x1546f960.negError{id: 4512} + 1*UILabel:0x143f92e0.Width{id: 4515}
    0x1546f9a0.posErrorMarker{id: 4513} == 0 + 1*UILabel:0x143f92e0.Height{id: 4508} + 1*0x1546f9a0.negError{id: 4514}
    0x1546fb80.posErrorMarker{id: 4528} == 0 + 1*0x1546fb80.negError{id: 4529} + 1*UILabel:0x143fa540.Width{id: 4536}
    0x1546fbc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4531} == 21 + 1*0x143fa830.marker{id: 4470} + 1*0x1546fbc0.negError{id: 4533}
    0x1546ffc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4539} == 175 + 1*0x143f9d80.marker{id: 4472} + 1*0x1546ffc0.negError{id: 4540}
    0x15470010.posErrorMarker{id: 4543} == 0 + 1*UILabel:0x143f9c60.Height{id: 4534} + 1*0x15470010.negError{id: 4544}
    0xc3b2000.negError{id: 2930} == 95 + -1*0x136306d0.marker{id: 2812} + 1*0xc3b2000.posErrorMarker{id: 2929}
    0xc3c12c0.negError{id: 2932} == 95 + -1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + 1*0xc3c12c0.posErrorMarker{id: 2931}
    0xc3c1cf0.posErrorMarker{id: 2933} == 61 + 1*0x1362ffd0.marker{id: 2820} + 1*0xc3c1cf0.negError{id: 2934}
    0xc3c1d30.negError{id: 2936} == 11 + -1*0x13630000.marker{id: 2818} + 1*0xc3c1d30.posErrorMarker{id: 2935}
    ProgramTableCell:0x143f8520.Height{id: 4576} == 100 + 1*0x14187d90.marker{id: 4585}
    ProgramTableCell:0x143f8520.Width{id: 4573} == 768 + 1*0x14401520.marker{id: 4413} + 1*0x125b3cd0.marker{id: 4581}
    ProgramTableCell:0x143f8520.minX{id: 4579} == 0 + 1*0x14187a10.marker{id: 4578} + -0.5*0x125b3cd0.marker{id: 4581}
    ProgramTableCell:0x143f8520.minY{id: 4580} == 100 + 1*0x125b3d00.marker{id: 4584} + -0.5*0x14187d90.marker{id: 4585}
    ProgramTableCell:0x15584d90.Height{id: 4398} == 100 + 1*0x14402ca0.marker{id: 4406}
    ProgramTableCell:0x15584d90.Width{id: 4395} == 768 + 1*0x14404210.marker{id: 4404} + 1*0x14401520.marker{id: 4413}
    ProgramTableCell:0x15584d90.minX{id: 4401} == 0 + 1*0x14404340.marker{id: 4400} + -0.5*0x14404210.marker{id: 4404}
    ProgramTableCell:0x15584d90.minY{id: 4402} == 0 + 1*0x14404240.marker{id: 4405} + -0.5*0x14402ca0.marker{id: 4406}
    UIButton:0x13630bb0.Height{id: 2825} == 62 + 1*0x13630b20.marker{id: 2824}
    UIButton:0x13630bb0.Width{id: 2823} == 120 + 1*0x13630b50.marker{id: 2822}
    UIButton:0x13630bb0.minX{id: 2863} == 55 + 1*0x1362f5e0.marker{id: 2862}
    UIButton:0x13630bb0.minY{id: 2861} == 177 + 1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + 1*0x13630000.marker{id: 2818} + 1*0x1362f730.marker{id: 2851} + 1*0x1362f6a0.marker{id: 2856} + 1*0x1362f610.marker{id: 2860}
    UIButton:0x13631230.Height{id: 2835} == 126 + 1*0x13631030.marker{id: 2834}
    UIButton:0x13631230.Width{id: 2833} == 120 + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832}
    UIButton:0x13631230.minX{id: 2840} == 55 + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841}
    UIButton:0x13631230.minY{id: 2837} == 43 + 1*0x1362f880.marker{id: 2836}
    UIImageView:0x1362fdf0.Height{id: 2829} == 20 + 1*0x1362faf0.marker{id: 2828}
    UIImageView:0x1362fdf0.Width{id: 2831} == 20 + 1*0x1362fac0.marker{id: 2830}
    UIImageView:0x1362fdf0.minX{id: 2866} == 65 + 1*0x1362f580.marker{id: 2865}
    UIImageView:0x1362fdf0.minY{id: 2868} == 197 + 1*0x136301f0.marker{id: 2816} + 1*0x1362f7f0.marker{id: 2844} + 1*0x1362f550.marker{id: 2867}
    UIImageView:0x13630520.Height{id: 2817} == 120 + 1*0x136301f0.marker{id: 2816}
    UIImageView:0x13630520.Width{id: 2815} == 120 + 1*0x13630220.marker{id: 2814}
    UIImageView:0x13630520.minX{id: 2847} == 55 + -1*0x13630220.marker{id: 2814} + 1*0x13631060.marker{id: 2832} + 1*0x1362f850.marker{id: 2838} + 1*0x1362f820.marker{id: 2841} + -1*0x1362f7c0.marker{id: 2846}
    UIImageView:0x13630520.minY{id: 2845} == 43 + 1*0x1362f7f0.marker{id: 2844}
    UIImageView:0x13632240.Height{id: 2811} == 120 + 1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810}
    UIImageView:0x13632240.Width{id: 2813} == 120 + 1*0x136306d0.marker{id: 2812}
    UIImageView:0x13632240.minX{id: 2850} == 55 + 1*0x1362f760.marker{id: 2849}
    UIImageView:0x13632240.minY{id: 2852} == 43 + 1*0x1362f730.marker{id: 2851}
    UIImageView:0x143f8830.Height{id: 4463} == 90 + 1*0x143f89a0.marker{id: 4462}
    UIImageView:0x143f8830.Width{id: 4461} == 90 + 1*0x143f8970.marker{id: 4460}
    UIImageView:0x143f8830.minX{id: 4479} == 656 + -1*0x143f8970.marker{id: 4460} + -1*0x143fad90.posErrorMarker{id: 4487} + 1*0x143fad90.negError{id: 4488} + -1*0x143fadc0.posErrorMarker{id: 4490} + 1*0x143fadc0.negError{id: 4491} + -1*UILabel:0x143f8bb0.Width{id: 4493} + 1*0x1435c670.marker{id: 4556}
    UIImageView:0x143f8830.minY{id: 4476} == 5 + 1*0x143fad00.posErrorMarker{id: 4474} + -1*0x143fad00.negError{id: 4475}
    UIImageView:0x15585220.Height{id: 4274} == 90 + 1*0x155854b0.marker{id: 4273}
    UIImageView:0x15585220.Width{id: 4272} == 90 + 1*0x15585480.marker{id: 4271}
    UIImageView:0x15585220.minX{id: 4290} == 5 + 1*0x143e8f30.posErrorMarker{id: 4288} + -1*0x143e8f30.negError{id: 4289}
    UIImageView:0x15585220.minY{id: 4287} == 5 + 1*0x143e9030.posErrorMarker{id: 4285} + -1*0x143e9030.negError{id: 4286}
    UILabel:0x13630060.Height{id: 2819} == 21 + 1*0x13630000.marker{id: 2818}
    UILabel:0x13630060.Width{id: 2821} == 230 + 1*0x1362ffd0.marker{id: 2820}
    UILabel:0x13630060.minX{id: 2855} == -1 + 1*0x1362f6d0.marker{id: 2854}
    UILabel:0x13630060.minY{id: 2857} == 177 + 1*0x13630700.marker{id: 2810} + 1*0x1362f730.marker{id: 2851} + 1*0x1362f6a0.marker{id: 2856}
    UILabel:0x143e6880.Height{id: 4282} == 21 + 1*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281}
    UILabel:0x143e6880.Width{id: 4350} == 192 + -1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + -1*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + 1*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + 1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + -1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + -1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + 1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + -1*0x135ef9f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4345} + 1*0x135ef9f0.negError{id: 4346} + -1*0x135ef7f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4348} + 1*0x135ef7f0.negError{id: 4349} + 1*0x14408c80.marker{id: 4385}
    UILabel:0x143e6880.minX{id: 4347} == 390 + 1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283} + 1*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + -1*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + -1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + 1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + 1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + -1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340} + 1*0x135ef9f0.posErrorMarker{id: 4345} + -1*0x135ef9f0.negError{id: 4346}
    UILabel:0x143e6880.minY{id: 4308} == 39 + 1*0x155857a0.marker{id: 4275} + 1*0x143e9110.posErrorMarker{id: 4291} + -1*0x143e9110.negError{id: 4292} + 1*0x135ef9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4343} + -1*0x135ef9c0.negError{id: 4344}
    UILabel:0x143e95d0.Height{id: 4321} == 21 + 1*0x135f0490.marker{id: 4281} + 1*0xc0c8860.posErrorMarker{id: 4304} + -1*0xc0c8860.negError{id: 4305} + 1*0x135f0040.posErrorMarker{id: 4319} + -1*0x135f0040.negError{id: 4320} + -1*0x135f0070.posErrorMarker{id: 4323} + 1*0x135f0070.negError{id: 4324} + 1*0x135ef9c0.posErrorMarker{id: 4343} + -1*0x135ef9c0.negError{id: 4344}
    UILabel:0x143e95d0.Width{id: 4284} == 175 + 1*0x135e1790.marker{id: 4283}
    UILabel:0x143e95d0.minX{id: 4329} == 207 + 1*0x135f0210.posErrorMarker{id: 4331} + -1*0x135f0210.negError{id: 4332} + -1*0x135efb30.posErrorMarker{id: 4334} + 1*0x135efb30.negError{id: 4335} + 1*0x135efb90.posErrorMarker{id: 4339} + -1*0x135efb90.negError{id: 4340}
    UILabel:0x143e95d0.minY{id: 4322} == 39 + 1*0x155857a0.marker{id: 4275} + 1*0x143e9110.posErrorMarker{id: 4291} + -1*0x143e9110.negError{id: 4292} + 1*0x135f0070.posErrorMarker{id: 4323}libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is this? It seem to have something to do with autolayout or? 
As far as I can see the cell uses autolayout but in the code ceratin views (eg a progressView) are removed or added by using addSubview:. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Hmm... looks odd. Do you have an exception breakpoint? It might give you a clue as to which line of code is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes. The line is where I get the cell. dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier

Comment: Hmm... which version of Xcode?

Comment: xcode 5.1.1 is the version

Comment: having same error here too :(